# Using Non-default Constructors with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net

I've read in the documentation that NHibernate requires classes to implement a default constructor that it can use when instantiating objects.  I was wondering if it was possible to supply parameters to NHibernate and have it instantiate objects using a particular constructor.

Currently I am getting around this by using ADO.NET and explicitly specifying parameters, but it would be nice if this could be handled automatically through some hibernate mapping property or method.

Answer (score 4):

Try look here:

[Working with NHibernate without default constructors](http://kozmic.pl/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/)

Comment: This article is great. Well written and detailed.